# Where do I ask for opinions?

Tags: support

I work in an IT area and sometimes I need a suggestion on what library or framework to use in certain situations. But when I read what topics I can and cannot ask on a site (especially on Stack Overflow), I see that I cannot ask for suggestions like this. So, on what site can I ask for this kind of suggestions that are related to programming?

Comment: The best solution is always 1) find the latest options through your favorite search engine 2) prototype using candidates you believe are viable 3) pick the one you find works best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can make use of [software recommendation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

The [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) mentions

> [...] While this includes software libraries for development use [...]

asking for library suggestions should be on-topic there. Ensure you make your question as localized as possible, include the particular task you want to accomplish and the expected set of features you want to have in the tool.

Comment: I for one voted down for blatant omission of the critical part of the quoted text from help center: "Good software recommendation requests have two components: * A **purpose** — a task to accomplish, a user story * Some **objective requirements** — a minimum set of features

Please read our **[question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)** before posting. Always state your requirements explicitly..."

Comment: @gnat but the same is mention in my answer, and a link added to the said help center. What else needed?

Comment: why asking me, I am already biased. Just go to [SR main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), refer your answer here and ask them if it's okay. If you want to learn something _especially_ useful for an active Stack Overflow user, ask them also about what "Duga chat room" over there is for